# C strchr causing "Invalid read of size 1" in valgrind

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, strchr

I'm running through a program and although the code is working fine, Valgrind is showing an 'Invalid write of Size 1' and Address 0x1ffefffa00 is on thread 1's stack.This has happened using both `strchr` and `strchrn`, another function in the program.

I've tried using index to locate the comma, as well as `strchr` and my `strchr` functions but all keep returning the same warning in Valgrind

```
typedef struct data_s Data;

struct data_s {
    float temperature;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
```

};

```
char* getData(FILE* filename) {
    char buffer[INPUT_LINE_MAX];
    char* dataLine = fgets(buffer, INPUT_LINE_MAX, filename);
    return dataLine;
}

Data* buildData(FILE* filename) {
    char* readLine = getData(filename);
    Data* new = malloc(sizeof(Data) + 1);
    char* comma1 = strchr(readLine, ',');
```

the rest of the code below `comma1` is irrelevant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 1):

One problem will be that in the function `getData()` you are returning a pointer to a buffer that goes out of scope as soon as the function returns.

`char buffer[INPUT_LINE_MAX];` is declared as a local variable and will be allocated on the stack. The memory for this will no longer be used when the function returns. Thus in you program, in the function `buildData()` the variable `readLine` points to a location on the stack that will probably be overwritten, at least in part, by the next function call(s)

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my code around and it's working!